# how can i add some more space to my /home in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, home-directory, disk-usage

while installing windows in my machine, i some how gave 100 Gb to store the back-up (I am really not getting the exact name, so please pardon me for using back-up word) and while i was creating ubuntu on windows, being stupid i did provided sufficient space for my home directory. At present my ubuntu structure is

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6        46G  7.0G   37G  17% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            2.7G  4.0K  2.7G   1% /dev
tmpfs           556M  3.0M  553M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.8G   45M  2.7G   2% /run/shm
none            100M   20K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda8       9.3G  3.5G  5.4G  40% /usr
/dev/sda7       4.6G  3.8G  599M  87% /home
/dev/sr0        3.1G  3.1G     0 100% /media/shailendra/My DVD
/dev/sda2       200G  142G   59G  71% /media/shailendra/4AE85C73E85C5F6F
```

My system had 500 gb space out of which i can only see 268 gb. I really don't have any idea, where the rest of space is gone. I don't want to format my machine fully and then start working again. Can some one help me, to add some more space to my `/home` directory.

Comment: `mount` only shows mounted partitions. To list every partitioned and unpartitioned space, use `sudo parted -l`.

Answer (score 2):

Boot into the Ubuntu LiveCD and open up the Partition Manager.
Then shrink the NTFS and grow the ext3 drive as fits, then apply the changes.

That is all it takes.

[source](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-879225.html)